# How to deploy auto-assigning and incrementing number for primary key related to SQLITE?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I faced an problem related to maintaining an ID entry for database records.
It looks like when I assign it manually and then create relevant data then it is ok.
Auto-assignment however does not seem to work:

```
public class Notification
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int N_Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string Topic { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

This is maintained in Notification class. 
Code related to table creation:

```
public Database()
    {
        _sqlconnection = DependencyService.Get<SQLiteInterface>().GetConnection();
        _sqlconnection.CreateTable<Student>();
        _sqlconnection.CreateTable<Notification>();
    }
```

I also did following:

- added `, NotNull" after "AutoIncrement`,
- added line with `[Table(nameof(Notification))]`.

Could you please let me know if this is related to configuration of public int N_ID or if you have faced similar issue?

Comment: you can used third party software in creating Sqlite database and manage table like navicat for sqlite.

Comment: Thank you for the post however if possible I would rather seek code related solution.